# jQuery Ui Dialog: how to prevent multiple dialog openings and avoid to limit at just one

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, modal-dialog

I need to use jquery ui dialog in order to open a dialog and let users open it anytime they want.
I used the following code but the point is that the dialog can open just once. I cannot open it a second time. What's wrong with the code?

```
$j(document).on("click", "p.span", function () {
 $j('<div></div>').dialog({
        modal: true,
        closeText: 'Close',
        title: "Title",
        open: function () {
            var markup = '<p>Text block</p>';
            $j(this).html(markup);
            $j(document).unbind('click');

    return false; 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you add an attribute on `p.span` like `data-open` and give it a value of `0`, when the user clicks it, check if the value is `0`, if yes open the `modal` and change the value to `1`, if no then do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:**

```js
$(document).on("click", "p span", function () { // changed p.span to p span(if you're targeting element with class span, you don't need to change this)
 $('<div></div>').dialog({
        modal: true,
        closeText: 'Close',
        title: "Title",
        open: function () {
            var markup = '<p>Text block</p>';
            $(this).html(markup);
            // remove this line if you don't want to limit it only once
            $(document).off('click', 'p span'); // unbind is deprecated, use off instead
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p><span>Hola Amigo!</span></p>
```

**Method 2:**

```js
$(document).on("click", "p span", function () { // changed p.span to p span(if you're targeting element with class span, you don't need to change this)

// Check the default value 
if($(this).attr('data-open') == 0){
  $(this).attr('data-open', 1); // Change the default value
  $('<div></div>').dialog({
        modal: true,
        closeText: 'Close',
        title: "Title",
        open: function () {
            var markup = '<p>Text block</p>';
            $(this).html(markup);
        }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- Add a custom attribute with default value 0 -->
<p><span data-open='0'>Hola Amigo!</span></p>
```

See if this helps you.

Comment: Great! But why does the dialog open just once? What do you suggest to do in order to let user open it n times?

Comment: Oh wait, did you want it to open multiple times or did you want it to open only once?

Comment: I've added a comment in the first snippet, follow it if want to open it multiple times.

Comment: The point is that, if I get rid of off() function, then I can start n instances of the dialog. One above the other. Isn't there a way to manage a open/close/open/close/etc loop?

Comment: I don't think you can run multiple instances once the `pop-up` is opened, the background is disabled. Check the demo and try clicking outside the `pop-up`

Comment: It seems like default jquery and jquery ui package included in the latest wordpress are not the same you request to load. Can this make it not work as expected? I have jquery 1.12.4, jQuery UI Dialog 1.11.4 & jQuery UI Core 1.11.4.

Comment: I guess. It might be a bug, I've included the latest version of `jQuery(3.3.1)` and `jQuery UI(1.12.1)`.